# selenium java @FindAll(@FindBy) how to wait number of element to be

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm using this method :

```java
@findAll(@FindBy(id = "1"))
List<WebElement> myList;
```

When I try to call `mylist.get(0)`, this gives me a list with size 0,
how can I wait so the number of elements in the list will be more than 0?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is typing mistake, but could you please try to update @findAll to @FindAll? e.g.`@FindAll(@FindBy(id = "1"))` and try again?

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium Java you can use the following expected condition
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(element,expectedElementsAmount))`
Where `element` is the element locator and `expectedElementsAmount` expected Elements Amount in Integer format.
There is also `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(element,expectedElementsAmount))` condition to wait for number of elements to be more than some amount.
See more details on the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) page